# Is there any shortcut or feature to copy the preview output from Photoshop, without going to export option?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I remember I once saw something related to it on a blog, but didn't give much attention to it. I had made a note at that time which was:

> Ctrol Shift E to preview layer

I'm not fully sure whether it was for solving this problem or not.

Anyway, let me explain what I need:

When I design something (there are a lot of layers), I have to make a lot of changes according to requirements from my directors. So every time, I have to go to export and **preview** it as web from there. Since the file is big, it takes a bit to open the output in browser. Then I copy the image from there (right click, copy. I guess it's OS feature) and send them to feedback.

I like copying the image because it works for me and it's easy then exporting it again and again, until it's ready for approval.

Another approach is, group all layers, duplicate it, press `Control + E` (on Windows). It just rasterizes all. Then I can simply copy it. But at times it may be destructive (sometimes I lose my artwork, because by mistake I save the document without copying and directly merging it).

So is there any already existing feature in Photoshop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (new Layer)

Then...

<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (Merge Visible)

Creates a new layer then merges everything visible on that layer, leaving all other layers as they are.

You can then Right-Click/Control-Click and `Duplicate Layer` to a `New` document.. save... It'll save much faster.

---

I suggest both commands to avoid merging visible on a necessary layer. If you add a new layer before merging visible, there's no chance you'll destroy something unintentionally. And if you were to mistakenly save the file.. you simply save with an extra layer that can be removed.

Comment: I just tried Cntl + Shift + E, the behaviour is little strange. Althout I get a output, but all other layers hide. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @Vikas Add **option**. Check the shortcuts I posted carefully. Command-Shift-E merges **everything** and removes all other layers below.

Comment: No. I mean the solution you gave works. But I was just curious of Command-Shift-E use. Is there any official link where I can read this? I guess that would be better.

Comment: The [Help files](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html) list many of them. I have no idea how in-depth that list may be. There may be a couple "deeper" shortcuts missing.

Comment: I got the difference. Control + Shift + E just merges the visible layers. So earlier I had thought it merges all layers, but HIDES all of them. I was wrong. It just don't hide them, it just LEAVES already hidden layers. Right?

Comment: Command-Shift-E = Merge this and all layers below, regardless of visibility to a single layer -- Command-OPTION-Shift-E = Merge **visible** layers on this layer, leaving other layers as they are

Comment: I have 2 groups. Each has 2 layers (1 visible, 1 hidden).  The cursor is on top group currently. I press Cntl + Shift + E. Finally I see 1 rasterized layer with output, and 2 hidden layers below it. I'm talking about those 2 hidden layers. So I guess it didn't merge all layers, only the visible ones. I guess you're wrong here ;)

Comment: On **groups** Command-Shift-E means "Merge this group"

Comment: A bit difficult to understand here what you're saying. Maybe needs practical approach from my side. But your answer answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

In the Layers palette, make sure you have selected the topmost layer that has visible pixels. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to make a new layer that has a rasterised version of all visible layers.

Comment: Disclaimer: on mobile atm, so I can't check 100% correctness.

Comment: Anyway, Control + Shift + E has some meaning?

Comment: Now I can't decide which answer to accept.